# Changing constant variables in C

Tags: c, constants, undefined-behavior, string-literals

Why are we able to change constant variables using a pointer, but we can't change a constant string index value using a pointer?
For example,

Case1: Changing constant variables using pointers, this works fine.

```
int main() 
{ 
    const int var = 10; 

    int *ptr = &var; 
    *ptr = 12; 

    printf("var = %d\n", var); //12

    return 0; 
}
```

Case2: Changing constant string using pointers, this gives compiler error

```
 int main() 
    { 
        char * a = "test";//test is in ROM, a is a pointer to its start address in ROM

       a[3] = 'M';//error

        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: You can't do either. Both invoke Undefined Behaviour. If one crashes and the other transfers the money in your account to my account, all is well in the UB-land. On a full-moon day your program might as well work as you expect :)

Comment: However the first one seems to be totally legal, I know its logically wrong, but are BOTH wrong according to c standard?

Comment: @AhmadAnwar Yes, both are wrong according to the C standard. The first works *in practice only*.

Comment: "we can" [Says who?](https://ideone.com/wtk8Bq)

Comment: [C11 6.7.3p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6): "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: Try making `var` a global variable.

Comment: Maybe it works if you use `*(a+3)` instead of `a[3]`

Comment: @dan1st: `*(a + 3)` and `a[3]` are 100% absolutely identical.

Comment: I know. But maybe the compiler does not recognize that you modify the pointer.

Comment: @AhmadAnwar Can you clarify your question?  You said your first program, that attempts to modify a const int, "works fine", but I would expect to get warnings or errors from the compiler, and indeed under my compiler I do.  For the second program, on the other hand, that attempts to modify a string literal, I would expect to get a *run-time* error, not a compiler error (and, again, on my computer, that's exactly what happens).

Comment: @Steve Summit GCC only gave me a warning that a non-const pointer is pointing to const data, however I was able to change the value, in the string case, we can't change any index's value.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The global trick made it un-edit able, can you clarify why?

Comment: @AhmadAnwar Yes, when it's a local variable, it is on the stack, which is always writable. If it's in global memory and const, the compiler will put it in a read-only section.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Wait, so const local variables are in the stack not in a read-only section?

Comment: @AhmadAnwar all local non-static variables are on the stack, so yes. In case 2, the variable `a` is a *pointer* to a string, and this pointer is on the stack. But it points to a string which is in read-only memory.

Answer (score 2):

The both programs are ill-formed and have undefined behavior.

According to the C Standard (6.7.3 Type qualifiers)

> 6 If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, **the behavior is undefined**.

It seems that the first program produces the expected result only due to the fact that the variable `var` has automatic storage duration. That is the compiler did not place it in a read-only memory.

All string literals (though in C they have types of non-constant arrays opposite to C++) have the static storage duration and usually are collected by the compiler in a literal pool that is stored in a read-only memory.

In any case according to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: It is misleading to state that string literals are “usually” collected the compiler and stored in read-only memory. While you may use general-purpose multi-user systems most commonly, they are not actually the most common systems in the world, and there are a variety of systems. It is not “unusual” for a compiler to store string literals in writeable memory. It could be better to say it is “common.”

Comment: The C++ standard has a concept of well-formed and ill-formed programs, but the C standard does not use this terminology. A compiler may accept a program that violates constraints.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does not mean that I may not use this term.:)

Comment: It means that your answer is misleading and possibly incorrect. It incorrectly presents the rules of C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No the statement is very clear and unambiguous

Comment: Neither “clear” nor “unambiguous” means correct. And it is not unambiguous; there is no definition for “well-formed” or “ill-formed” in C stated in either the C standard or this answer. Therefore there is no good meaning for “ill-formed” at hand. It is ambiguous.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In some languages a term has a definition in other languages it is used with the common sense. It does not mean that you may not use a term with the common sense. Consider for example the term generic.

Comment: Common sense is insufficient to clarify what the term means. Common sense would say that “well-formed” or “ill-formed” is about the **form** of the program, which is readily interpreted to mean its syntax and grammar. But there is nothing wrong with the grammar of the programs in the question; they are accepted by a parser that uses the grammar specified in the C standard. The C++ standard added semantic rules to “ill-formed.” That was the choice of its committee, and possibly not a good one. But it would not make sense to say “ill-formed” for C merely obeys all the semantic rules. Some…

Comment: … rules apply only conditionally, if the program does certain things at execution time. So defining “ill-formed” for C to mean anything more than the grammar and less than obeying all semantic rules is tricky. And it is certainly not covered in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a `const int` and then assigning a value to it through a pointer is undefined behavior. Modifying this variable through a pointer will not throw an exception when it is allocated in a writable memory though (seems that your compiler is allocating the variable in the stack).

However when you declare `char *str = "test";` the string `"test"` is usually allocated in a read-only memory section (which seems to be your case). Thus probably throwing an `ACCESS_VIOLATION` when you try to change it through `a[3] = 'M';`.

To stress that out though: both cases should be considered undefined behavior.

Comment: String literals are common allocated in read-only memory, but this is of course not true on systems that do not support this. C can be implemented for even very tiny processors in embedded systems, which lack the protection features of general-purpose multi-user systems. It is undoubtedly the cause in OP’s case, but it is not a rule that strings are “always” allocated in read-only memory.

Comment: IMHO assigning to a constant via pointer is not "undefined behavior"; it's a "programming error". No need to discuss what might be the consequences of it: The compile does not need to allocate an actual variable for it, but could optimize it away. It could also place the constant in the text segment, causing an access violation on write attempts for modern systems.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least four factors involved in the observations made in the question.

### 1. Implicitly removing `const` should generate a warning

Consider this:

```
int *ptr = &var;
```

In this statement, `&var` is a pointer to a `const int`, but `ptr` is a pointer to `int`. This violates the constraints for simple assignments in C 2018 6.5.16.1 (which apply because the rules for initialization in 6.7.9 11 refer to them). In this case, the left operand must have all the qualifiers of the right operand and be of otherwise compatible type.

Because a constraint is violated, a compiler conforming to the C standard is required to issue a diagnostic. You either used a non-conforming compiler to compile this program or you ignored the diagnostic and executed the program anyway.

Since a constraint is violated, the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard.

An important principle here is that the C standard **does not prevent you from breaking some rules**. In this case, it merely does not guarantee what will happen.

### 2. The behavior of attempting to modify `const` object is not defined by the C standard

In this line:

```
*ptr = 12;
```

the program attempts to modify the constant `var` through a pointer. This violates C 6.7.3 7, which says:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

(The expression `*ptr` is an lvalue with non-const-qualified type.)

As above, the C standard does not prevent you from breaking this rule; it merely does not define what will happen.

What happens when you break this rule? It depends on how the compiler treated your program. Several things are common:

- If the object is static and `const`, the compiler might assign it to a read-only location of memory. Then attempting to modify it would cause a memory access violation and crash the program.
- If the object is automatic (defined inside a function with default storage), the compiler might assign it to the stack. The stack is both readable and writeable (it has to be writeable because we change the stack frequently, as routines are called and return). Thus, although the object is `const`, the compiler has no good way to put an automatic object into read-only memory. So it is on the stack and is writeable. Then attempting to modify it succeeds.
- The compiler, during optimization, modifies your program in various ways. This can cause hard-to-predict results when you attempt to modify a `const` object. The optimizer might recognize that the attempt is not defined by the C standard and simply remove the attempt from your program. But other results are possible too.

### 3. Due to historical language development, string literals are not `const`-qualified

At the time string literals were introduced to the C language, there was no `const` qualifier. There was merely a rule (at some point, if not initially), that you were not allowed to modify the elements of string literals.

When `const` was introduced to the C language, string literals could not be made `const` because this would cause many programs not to compile, because those programs were using `char *` to refer to elements in string literals. They were not modifying the string literals, but they were using these old pointer types to refer to them.

So string literals remained non-`const`-qualified.

### 4. The rule that modifying string literals is not supported remains

Another feature of string literals is that they may be consolidated. If you use `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` in one place in the program and you use the same string in another place in the program, even in a different translation unit, the compiler and linker are allowed to create just one instance of them in the executable file and in the memory of the loaded program. This feature was important for early programs, because machines had limited space, so combining copies of the same data was valuable.

This permission is in C 2018 6.4.5 7, which says, about string literals:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values.…

That paragraph also gives us the rule that the behavior of attempting to modify string literals is not defined by the C standard:

> … If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

The first rule of this paragraph is also a reason we need the second rule. If two string literal can be consolidated into one memory location, then a routine that changed what it thought of as its string could inadvertently change the data used by another routine, possibly in an entirely different part of the program written by a different person at a different company.

Thus, due to how the C language developed historically, string literals are not `const`-qualified, but the C standard does not support modifying them.

What happens when you break this rule? Commonly, string literals are put in a read-only portion of memory. When you attempt to modify them, a likely result is that your program causes a memory access violation and crashes. This is the proximate cause of the behavior you observed: The string was in read-only memory, and modifying it caused a crash, but the `ptr` object was on the stack, and modifying it “worked.” So the results are not a necessary consequence of the rules of C but were consequences of how your compiler behaved.